# Python - Assigning Matplotlib Xtick

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to recreate a longitude axis on a standard matplotlib plot. I started by creating an array using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
east = np.linspace(10, 180, 18)
west = np.linspace(-10, -180, 18)
west = west[::-1]
lons = np.concatenate((east, west))
```

when I try setting the array as my xticks on a subplot, using:

```
ax.set_xticks(lons)
```

The plot I end up with has xticks from -180 to 180 (least to greatest) rather than in the order I passed. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

With the line `ax.set_xticks()` you're setting *where* on your axis the tick positions occur, note that this doesn't tell `matplotlib` *what* to display at those positions.

If you want labelling other than the default you'll need to set that explicitly. You could use [`ax.set_xticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) after first setting your `xtick` positions as you've done in your question.